# Sqlite (C API) and query (select) on cyclic/symmetric values with user defined functions

Tags: c++, sqlite, user-defined-functions

I'm using Sqlite with C++ and have two similar problems :

1) I need to select 4 entries to make an interpolation.

For example, my table could look like this :

**angle (double) | color (double)**

```
  0            0.1
 30            0.5
 60            0.9
 90            1.5
...            ...
300            2.9
330            3.5
```

If I want to interpolate the value corresponding to 95°, I will use the entries 60°, 90°, 120° and 150°.
To get those entries, my request will be `SELECT color FORM mytable WHERE angle BETWEEN 60 and 150`, no big deal.

Now if I want 335°, I will need 300°, 330°, 360°(=0°) and 390°(=30°).
My query will then be `SELECT color FORM mytable WHERE angle BETWEEN 300 and 330 OR angle BETWEEN 0 and 30`.
I can't use `SELECT color FORM mytable WHERE angle BETWEEN 300 and 390` because this will only return 2 colors.

Can I use the C API and user defined functions to include some kind of modulo meaning in my queries ?
It would be nice if I could use a user defined function to use the query `[...] BETWEEN 300 and 390` and get as result the rows 300, 330, 0 and 30.

2) An other table looks like this :

**speed (double) |   color (double)   |   var (double)**

```
 0              0.1         0
10              0.5         1
20              0.9         2
30              1.5         3
...             ...         ...
```

In reality due to symmetry, color(speed) = color(-speed) but var(-speed) = myfunc(var(speed)).
I would like to make queries such as `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE speed BETWEEN -20 and 10` and be able to make a few operations with the API on the "virtual" rows with a negative speed and return them as a regular result.

For example I would like the result of the query `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE speed BETWEEN -20 and 10` to be like this :

**speed (double) |   color (double)   |   var (double)**

```
-20             0.9      myfunc(2)
-10             0.5      myfunc(1)
  0             0.1        0
 10             0.5        1
```

Is that possible ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a query with two intervals :

SELECT * from mytable WHERE (speed >= MIN(?1,?2) AND speed <= MAX(?1,?2)) OR ((MAX(?1,?2) > 360) AND (speed >= 0 AND speed <= MAX(?1,?2)%360));

This example works fine if ?1 and ?2 are positive.

Comment: This kind of query allows indeed to select a discontinuous intervals, but it doesn't answer my question. I would like to know if I can use a "standard" query, all the work being done by user-defined functions...